# Hugepages seems to be stuck

Tags: linux, memory-usage

I'm running certain applications over DPDK, to be memory conservative, I'm continuously adjusting the number of hugepages by setting "nr_hugepages"

```
echo 8192> /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages

cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i huge  
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:    8192
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB

free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            188          17         159           0          11         170
Swap:           191           0         191
```

However, when I reached 64K, I seem to get stuck, and can't get the Hugepages changed again

```
echo 65536  > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages

sudo hugeadm --pool-list
      Size  Minimum  Current  Maximum  Default
   2097152    65536    65536    65536        *
1073741824        0        0       

cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i huge
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:   65536
HugePages_Free:       64
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Now, even if I set the nr_hugepages to 512

```
echo 512  > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
```

nr_hugepages read back as 64K

```
cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
65472
```

Comment: Did you release the huge page which are held by the primary application running? what is update, after terminating the process?

Comment: Hey Vipin, this is Morgan Yang (your former coworker in Radisys). So yes, I ended up rolling back to an older combination of DPDK and Kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly faced this issue and finally found the root cause and workaround for this issue.
This is mostly common when using DPDK application using DPDK version till 18.05.

The issue is when we stop the DPDK application or DPDK application crashes. The hugepages created or used by DPDK will not be freed automatically. It expects to reuse by secondary process.

Issue could be like you removed /mnt/huge and trying to modify the nr_hugepage

```
Numa case:
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages

echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages

non-NUMA case:
echo 0 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
```

steps to follow while un-mapping hugepage:

1. ls -l /mnt/huge/ .
   rm -rf rtemap_* (if there are any "rtemap_*" delete all)
2. mount | grep huge .

```
   hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)
```

3. ls /dev/hugepages

```
rtemap_0     rtemap_1202  rtemap_1408  rtemap_1613  rtemap_1819  rtemap_2023  rtemap_387  rtemap_592  rtemap_798
rtemap_1     rtemap_1203  rtemap_1409  rtemap_1614  rtemap_182   rtemap_2024  rtemap_388  rtemap_593  rtemap_799
```

If abive files are present delete all of them.

4. sudo umount /mnt/huge
5. sudo rm -R /mnt/huge
6. Then write 0 to nr_hugepages mentioned in the beginning.

Sample Output:

```
[root@localhost hugepages]# cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge
AnonHugePages:    161792 kB
HugePages_Total:    4096
HugePages_Free:     4096
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB

# cat /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
2048
# cat /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
2048
# cat /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages
4096
# cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
4096

# echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
# echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
# cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge
AnonHugePages:    161792 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up rolling back a year ago for the sake of stablility. I'm glad you answered, my previous work around was to reboot!

Comment: @user2066671 Sure, no problem. Even initially I used to reboot the system and suggest across my team. But then I wanted to provided better usability for our DPDK product and wanted to automate the entire DPDK env setup. There this problem was a hindrance and this approach helps.